# Insert a seperator string in a field value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have this this value generated using MAX and LPAD

result:
[image]

What i wanted is to put a dash after every 3rd number just like **000-000-002**, but i don't know what to do. Please help me.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: which backend language you are using?

Comment: I'm using php and mysql

Comment: What datatype is the field?

Comment: Always padded to 9 characters?

Comment: field data type is varchar..

Comment: always padded to 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use php `wordwrap()` function to put a specific character after the number of characters.The `wordwrap()` function wraps a string into new lines when it reaches a specific length.

```
$output = wordwrap($orNumber,3,'-',true);
```

> Note: This function may leave white spaces at the beginning of a line. So you have to trim your data to remove blank spaces

You can check the mannual here [PHP wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Comment: I recommend, you should do it from your php code only for dynamic length strings

Comment: thanks dude ill use your suggestions to make it dynamic

Answer (score 1):

MySQL :

```
set @var ='000000002';
select  CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTR(@var , 1, 3), SUBSTR(@var, 4,3), SUBSTR(@var, 7))
```

This will accept only varchar. For int values, numbers starting with 0 will not give correct error. Hence recommended to handle on PHP side.

Answer (score 1):

```
set @chr = '000000002';

select @chr,
         concat(substring(@chr,1,3),'-',substring(@chr,4,3),'-',substring(@chr,7,9)) hyphenated
```

Result

```
+-----------+-------------+
| @chr      | hyphenated  |
+-----------+-------------+
| 000000002 | 000-000-002 |
+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

if the length is always **fixed**, you can use `LEFT(), MID()`, and `RIGHT()`

```
update TABLE_NAME set orNumber = CONCAT(LEFT(orNumber, 3), '-' , MID(orNumber, 4, 3), '-' ,RIGHT(orNumber, 3))
```

find more on [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)